# Change from .Name property to String

Tags: powershell

Is this possible? I need to convert from `System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection` to a `String`.

i.e.

```
$ou = [ADSI]"LDAP://OU=Domain Controllers,DC=domain,DC=local"
foreach ($child in $ou.psbase.Children) {
    if ($child.ObjectCategory -like '*computer*') { 
        Write-Host $child.Name 
        if (Test-Connection -quiet $child.Name) {
            Test-Connection $child.name
            Invoke-GPUpdate $child.name
        }else{Write-Host "$child.Name is offline"}
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:
    $child.Name.ToString()

Edit: I just tested in my lab and actually this works, not sure why exactly:

```
$child | %{$_.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is here:

```
}else{Write-Host "$child.Name is offline"}
```

Try:

```
}else{Write-Host "$($child.Name) is offline"}
```

In a string variable's properties aren't expanded, you need to enclose it in `$()` notation.